# Grouping by categories and dates

Tags: r, date, grouping, categories

Suppose I have the following df:

```
id <-  c("abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "def")
date <- c("2007-12-31","2007-12-31", "2006-12-31", "2006-12-31", "2006-12-31")
quantity <- c(2,4,2,5,1)
type <- c("delta", "beta", "delta", "alpha", "beta") 
df <- cbind(id, date, quantity, type)
```

I wanted to group it by ID and Date and have variables for the types it into something like:

```
g_id <- c("abc", "abc", "def")
g_date <- c("2007-12-31", "2006-12-31", "2006-12-31")
g_quantity <- c(6,7,1)
g_alpha <- (0,5,0) 
g_beta <- (4,0,1)
g_delta <- (2,2,0)
df2 <- cbind(g_id, g_date, g_quantity, g_alpha, g_beta, g_delta)
```

What's the most concise way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Converting data to dataframe instead of matrix.

```
df <- data.frame(id, date, quantity, type)
```

You can get the data in wide format and sum the new columns row-wise.

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = type, values_from = quantity, 
                  values_fill = list(quantity = 0), names_prefix = 'g_') %>%
       mutate(g_quantity = rowSums(select(., starts_with('g_'))), .after  = date)


#   id    date       g_quantity g_delta g_beta g_alpha
#  <chr> <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 abc   2007-12-31          6       2      4       0
#2 abc   2006-12-31          7       2      0       5
#3 def   2006-12-31          1       0      1       0
```